# Emcc compiling c++ files not compiling correctly

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten, emcc

I used to have this:

```
void extra(int x){
   printf("Here's your number: %d\n", x);
}

EXTERN EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE void myFunction(int x){
    extra(x);
}
```

With a number input field and a button that would run myFunction with the value in the input field on pressing the button.

I have since changed it to:

```
// void extra(int x){
//     printf("Here's your number: %d\n", x);
// }

EXTERN EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE void myFunction(int x){
    printf("we're done!\n");
    //extra(x);
}
```

However, after compiling (using multiple commands, will get to that in a minute), pressing the button will still only output "Here's your number: [number]"

Commands I have tried:

```
emcc hello2.cpp -s STANDALONE_WASM -o hello2.wasm
emcc hello2.cpp -s STANDALONE_WASM
emcc -o hello2.html hello2.cpp -O3 -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -s "EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall']" (this updates my html file as well, which I don't want)
emcc -o hello2.js hello2.cpp -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -s "EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall']"
```

Comment: Are you sure that the modified source code is being compiled successfully? Maybe you are still executing the old code because the new one has some errors/warnings? For example, I see that the new `myFunction` still takes an `int x` parameter, but does not use it. This would probably cause the compiler to produce at least a warning (an unused parameter), if not an error. What happens  if you remove the name of the  unused parameter, i.e., try `myFunction(int)`, not  `myFunction(int x)`, for example?

Comment: @heapunderrun if I try it with your change, it will still do the original (here's your number: ...). Even if I delete the existing .wasm file and then run either of the compiling commands again...